# Infinity Looping using task data flow but still Blocking UI WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm-light

I have a windows page wpf, it has 3 datagrid. they are in an infinity loop using Task data flow. every data populate through binding the window freeze about 1-3 second. after i try to discard the binding from each datagrid. the window page run properly without freeze. below is part of my code, the flow of my code is start from start service method, the method createneverendingtask is the bottom of the code, i want there is no freezing if the data load to datagrid through binding.i use mvvm light.

```
    public void StartService()
    {
        StartContent = "Stop Service";
        StartToggle = false;

        wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        task = CreateNeverEndingTaskAsync((now, ct) => DoWorkAsync(ct), wtoken.Token);

        // Start the task.  Post the time.
        task.Post(DateTimeOffset.Now);
    }
    private Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => DoWork());
    }

    private async void DoWork()
    {
        LoadGrid();
        Helper.UiInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (NewAssignmentList.Count > 0)
            {
               several operations

            }                 
        });
    }
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
        AssigneeList = new ObservableCollection<Assignee>(
            Helper.DataReaderMapToList<Assignee>(
                cda.ExecuteReader("sp_AT_LoadAssignee")));
        NewAssignmentList = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>(
            Helper.DataReaderMapToList<Assignment>(
                cda.ExecuteReader("sp_AT_LoadAssignment 'NEW'")));
        DistributedAssignmentList = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>(
            Helper.DataReaderMapToList<Assignment>(
                cda.ExecuteReader("sp_AT_LoadAssignment '!NEW'")));
        ParameterList = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();

        AssigneeHeader = string.Format("Assignee : {0}",AssigneeList.Count);
        NewAssHeader = string.Format("New Assignment : {0}", NewAssignmentList.Count);
        DistAssHeader = string.Format("Distributed Assignment : {0}", DistributedAssignmentList.Count);

    }
ITargetBlock<DateTimeOffset> CreateNeverEndingTaskAsync(
    Func<DateTimeOffset, CancellationToken, Task> action,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Validate parameters.
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        // Declare the block variable, it needs to be captured.
        ActionBlock<DateTimeOffset> block = null;

        // Create the block, it will call itself, so
        // you need to separate the declaration and
        // the assignment.
        // Async so you can wait easily when the
        // delay comes.
        block = new ActionBlock<DateTimeOffset>(async now => {
            // Perform the action.  Wait on the result.
            await action(now, cancellationToken).
                // Doing this here because synchronization context more than
                // likely *doesn't* need to be captured for the continuation
                // here.  As a matter of fact, that would be downright
                // dangerous.
                ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Wait.
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(DelayService)), cancellationToken).
                // Same as above.
                ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Post the action back to the block.
            block.Post(DateTimeOffset.Now);
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            CancellationToken = cancellationToken
        });

        // Return the block.
        return block;
    }
```

Comment: `async void` is your problem. You should avoid doing async void. instead use `async Task`. Also you are using `async` without an `await`.

Comment: i've tried to add async task but still freeze bout 1-2 sec. the problem is in loadgrid() method that binding to a datagrid. if i remove all datagrid binding. it run without freeze.